# Why does VS2010 generate a syntax error for the following code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, lazy-initialization

The following code compiles fine under VS2013 and upwards as well as GCC

https://godbolt.org/z/-nKXB-

```
#include "boost/thread/once.hpp"
#include "boost/optional.hpp"
#include <functional>
/// A class to encapsulate lazy initialization of an object.
/// All instances of Lazy are thread safe and the factory
/// is guaranteed only to be called once. However if you
/// use this for member initialization DO NOT capture
/// this in the lambda. See LazyMember for an alternative
template <typename T>
class Lazy {
    mutable boost::once_flag _once;
    mutable boost::optional<T> _data;
    typedef std::function<T()> FactoryFn;
    FactoryFn _factory;
    void Init() const { boost::call_once([&]() { _data = _factory(); }, _once); }
public:
    Lazy(FactoryFn factory):
        _once(BOOST_ONCE_INIT),
        _factory(factory)
        {

        }

    T& Value() {
        Init();
        return *_data;
    }
};
```

to be used like

```
Lazy<int> i([]{return 10;}); // Pretend lambda is an expensive op
// and then some time later.
return i.Value()
```

Testing on VS2010 I get

```
1>Lazy.hpp(26):
error C2059: syntax error : ')' 1>       
Lazy.hpp(37)
: see reference to class template instantiation 'mw::Lazy<T>' being
compiled
1>Lazy.hpp(26):
error C2059: syntax error : ','
1>Lazy.hpp(28):
error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent
function body
```

A work around seems to be.

```
/// A class to encapsulate lazy initialization of an object.
/// All instances of Lazy are thread safe and the factory
/// is guaranteed only to be called once. However if you
/// use this for member initialization DO NOT capture
/// this in the lambda. See LazyMember for an alternative
template <typename T>
class Lazy {
    mutable boost::once_flag _once;
    mutable boost::optional<T> _data;
    typedef std::function<T()> FactoryFn;
    FactoryFn _factory;
    void Init() const { boost::call_once([&]() { _data = _factory(); }, _once); }
public:
    Lazy(FactoryFn factory):
        _factory(factory)
        {
          _once = BOOST_ONCE_INIT;
        }

    T& Value() {
        Init();
        return *_data;
    }

};
```

But what is the root problem?

Comment: The root problem is that 2010 was a LONG time ago.

Comment: MSVS 2010 is not known for it's C++11 compliance (heck, 2013 and 2015 had compliance issues as well).  If you don't have to support MSVS 2010, I would suggest dumping it.

Comment: I'm asking for a fix because I can't dump it. Nobody uses VS2010 because it's a fun and rewarding past time. :)